# Convert SOAP XML string to object or just read its contents

Tags: java, xml, soap

Am receiving a SOAP XML response from an endpoint and I am trying to read its' contents. I have tried a couple of methods but it keeps giving me null

```
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><soap:Body><CashOutPaymentRequestResponse xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><CashOutPaymentRequestResult><ResponseCode>1002</ResponseCode><ResponseDesc>FAC Code and Amount does not match, Contact your Admin.</ResponseDesc></CashOutPaymentRequestResult></CashOutPaymentRequestResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";

JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(cashOutPaymentRequestEnvelope.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
cashOutPaymentRequestEnvelope person = (cashOutPaymentRequestEnvelope) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
```

My method 2

```
Element rootdecryptedXml = XmlParseHelper.getStringXml(xml);
String responseUnEscapedXml = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(XmlParseHelper.getString("CashOutPaymentRequestResult", rootdecryptedXml));

String responseEscapedXml = XmlParseHelper.getString("CashOutPaymentRequestResult", rootdecryptedXml);

   System.out.println("step 1.. \n" + responseEscapedXml);

   Element root = XmlParseHelper.getStringXml(responseEscapedXml);

   System.out.println("step 2aa...\n" + XmlParseHelper.getString("ResponseCode", root));
   System.out.println("step 2bb...\n" + XmlParseHelper.getString("ResponseDesc", root));
```

None of the methods seem to work, they all give me null

My getString function

```
public static String getString(String tagName, Element element) {
    if (element == null) {
        return " ";
    }

    NodeList list = element.getElementsByTagName(tagName);

    if (list != null && list.getLength() > 0) {
        NodeList subList = list.item(0).getChildNodes();
        if (subList != null && subList.getLength() > 0) {
            return subList.item(0).getNodeValue();
        }
    }
    return " ";
}
```

My get StringXml

```
public static Element getStringXml(String responseXml) throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    Document document;
    Element rootdecryptedXml = null;
    DocumentBuilder builder;
    builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(responseXml)));
    rootdecryptedXml = document.getDocumentElement();
    return rootdecryptedXml;
}
```

Comment: Your first method using JAXB is sound - provided the JAXB Java class is the correct one for the given XML. You just need to feed the JAXB Unmarshaller just the relevant XML (the <CashOutPaymentRequestResult>...</CashOutPaymentRequestResult> part ) without the SOAP envelope. Use the SAAJ API to retrieve this and then unmarshall it. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19644-01/817-5452/wsgjaxm.html for SAAJ.

Comment: Thanks @Michal was able to get it to work. Would post the implementation

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Michal's comment I developed a solution to this

```
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes());
MessageFactory factory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage message = factory.createMessage(null, is);
NodeList listResult = message.getSOAPBody().getElementsByTagName("CashOutPaymentRequestResult");

for (int i = 0; i < listResult.getLength(); i++) {
    NodeList children = listResult.item(i).getChildNodes();
    
    for (int k = 0; k < children.getLength(); k++) {
        System.out.println(children.item(k).getNodeName());
        System.out.println(children.item(k).getTextContent());
        if (children.item(k).getNodeName().equals("ResponseCode")) {

        }
                
        if (children.item(k).getNodeName().equals("ResponseDesc")) {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late but if anyone comes here in the future searching/seeking for a solution like I did. I hope this helps you in a way. The other way is converting the XML to JSON using this org.json maven

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.json</groupId>
  <artifactId>json</artifactId>
  <version>20180130</version>
</dependency>
```

And your method that works around the fetch of data will be something like

```
private static void cashOutPayment(){
        String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><soap:Body><CashOutPaymentRequestResponse xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\"><CashOutPaymentRequestResult><ResponseCode>1002</ResponseCode><ResponseDesc>FAC Code and Amount does not match, Contact your Admin.</ResponseDesc></CashOutPaymentRequestResult></CashOutPaymentRequestResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>";
        JSONObject jsonObject = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
        String jsonString = jsonObject.toString();
        JSONObject jsonObject1 = ((JSONObject) jsonObject.get("soap:Envelope"))
                .getJSONObject("soap:Body").getJSONObject("CashOutPaymentRequestResponse")
                .getJSONObject("CashOutPaymentRequestResult");
        Integer responseCode = (Integer) jsonObject1.get("ResponseCode");
        String responseDesc = (String) jsonObject1.get("ResponseDesc");
        System.out.println("Response Code => "+responseCode+ " and Response Desc => "+responseDesc);
}
```